# How do I do /execute and filter it by name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a command block that has `/execute if entity` that will only execute on entities with a custom name, but I can’t figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
/execute if entity @e[name=“insert name”] (rest of command)
```

If it’s going to be one mob with this name as well as going to be released publicly, I recommend doing this:

```
/execute if entity @e[name=“insert name”,type=“insert mob”] (rest of command)
```